# Little shadowed squares at render with cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I haven't got a clue as how to define my problem in the title so let me explain better here:

I have got an object, that I have smoothed in object mode as well as in edit mode, I have put two lights on either side, but when I try and render it with cycles, I get something that looks like aliasing, that is to say that some faces which are in transition between shadow and light remain in shadow and there's a sharp cut between shadow and light at the top.[image: See the image below]

[image]
I have tried increasing the samples, and yet nothing changes, and that squarred shadow appears when I try to make a combined baking :(

Can someone help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: Adding a SubSurf modifier should fix this.

Comment: Hey! thank you for your answers, indeed I have seen the terminator problem meanwhile. I'll try the shade smooth solution! I was rather trying to avoid subsurfacing again because that's supposed to be a real time asset so I wanted to keep it as low poly as possible

Comment: Ok I've tried Mr Zak solution and it doesn't change anything. However I have noticed that it seems to be coming from the type of light: a sun light works much better than a hemi light, and it looks much better with hdri lighting. I'll keep investigating, thank you both anyway :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add an image of your mesh in edit mode in face selection mode. Also, consider uploading the file, you can use  http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add the resulting link as part of your original question.

Comment: No .blend file for us to look at?